# Learning C# from java POV

Tags: c#, java

What books would you guys recommend if one has been a java developer for years and is now trying to take the c#/asp.net route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read this whitepaper:

[C# From a Java Developers Perspective](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html)

Then, you can move onto books that cover the .NET framework, as you'll see the langauges differences are very quick to learn.

Answer (score 1):

[CLR Via C#](http://www.microsoft.com/MSPress/books/6522.aspx) is a great book for C# for people with experience programming.  Especially experience in other managed languages

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).

Answer (score 1):

I have recently done exactly this and found the two most valuable books to be:

> **[CLR via C#](http://www.amazon.co.uk/CLR-Via-Applied-Framework-Programming/dp/0735621632/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1227619247&sr=1-1) by Jeffrey Richter**.  Very well written and gives a great insight into the .net runtime - lots on the concepts you will already know from java such as garbage collection, threading, generics, etc.  Plus really good in depth coverage of c# constructs like delegates and events that don't come with java (yet).

and

> **[Pro C# and the .net 3.5 Platform](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-2008-NET-Platform-Fourth/dp/1590598849/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1227619142&sr=1-2) by Andrew Troelsen**.  This is much more of a general text on the .net ecosystem.  It has an excellent core language section, but then also gives a really good overview of the major libraries and apis - WPF, WCF, ASP.net, etc.

Those should provide you a solid foundation and are both pitched perfectly for the experienced programmer.  After that, you'll probably end up looking for something more specific to the technology you are working in - a detailed ASP.net book in your case - but I constantly refer to both of these, so it is money well spent imho.

Answer (score 0):

I find

> Pro C# with .NET 3.0, Special Edition 
>   by Andrew Troelsen 
>   Apress © 2007 (1238 pages)
>   ISBN:9781590598238

to be an excellent book.

Comment: There is a 3.5 specific printing of the book now as well.